# Intercepting WebView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Let if web page is bound to WebView, then is it possible to capture
the data that user is entering in the data fields of the web page?

In other words my activity need to intercept and interpret what is happening in
webview.... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the web page contain a submit-button, which activates Javascript, that accesses a JavaScript API that your application exposes. This way, you can make your web page communicate the data directly to your Android Java code.

Comment: Thank You Lars.I did followed the similar approach and was able to pull the data elements information from the page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to create malicious software. Would you please elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: lol, if I know how to write the malicious software, I would have become famous person. groups like fbi, cia, cbi would have try for me to arrest. Jokes aside,  What all I need is when user enters the data in html fields, I would need to capture that data and store it in local SQL database.  Anyways I was able to achieve this. Thank You.